# Why i can't access an object created in a method of an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say i have this code:

```
var m = 
{
    init: function(num, num2, num3)
    {
        this.num = num;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }
};

var t = 
{
    create: function()
    {
        var obj = Object.create(m);
        obj.init(1,2,3);
    }

};

t.create();
console.log(obj)
```

When executing this code i get this error:

> obj is not defined

How can I make `obj` work outside the method `create` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you come from a background of C# based on your code style ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `create` function to return the `obj`.
Then, you can do `var obj = t.create()`.

Here is the complete code:

```
var m = 
{
    init: function(num, num2, num3)
    {
        this.num = num;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }
};

var t = 
{
    create: function()
    {
        var obj = Object.create(m);
        obj.init(1,2,3);
        return obj;
    }

};

var obj = t.create();
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Always happy to help :D

Answer (score 1):

obj is a local variable to the function create. You need to return it to provide access to it outside of that function.

```
var t = 
{
    create: function()
    {
        var obj = Object.create(m);
        obj.init(1,2,3);
        return obj;
    }

};

var obj = t.create();
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning the object created would solve your issue. The obj is a local variable bound to the scope of the create function you cannot access it outside.

```
var m = 
{
    init: function(num, num2, num3)
    {
        this.num = num;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }
};

var t = 
{
    create: function()
    {
        var obj = Object.create(m);
        obj.init(1,2,3);
        return obj;
    }

};
let obj = t.create();
console.log(obj);
```